# wrong number of arguments (given 3, expected 1..2)

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-6

I am new to Rails 6 and I am getting above error. Please check the below code and help me to get out of this. Thanks!

```
has_many :coaches, ->{where('max_unit > 0 and active = 1').order('trim(full_name)')}, ->{select((Account.column_names - ['photo_file']).map { |column_name| "`accounts`.`#{column_name}`"})}, :through => :qualifications
```

> backtrace:
> ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (given 3, expected 1..2)):
>
> app/models/language.rb:9:in `<class:Language>' app/models/language.rb:1:in` '
> app/models/account.rb:142:in `manage_substitutions' app/controllers/extranet/homes_controller.rb:11:in` index'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are giving two lambdas as separate arguments here.

The first is

```
->{where('max_unit > 0 and active = 1').order('trim(full_name)')}`
```

The second is

```
->{select((Account.column_names - ['photo_file']).map { |column_name| "`accounts`.`#{column_name}`"})}
```

This is invalid. You should combine the two lambdas into one:

```
-> {
  where('max_unit > 0 and active = 1').
  order('trim(full_name)').
  select((Account.column_names - ['photo_file']).map { |column_name| "`accounts`.`#{column_name}`"})
}
```

You should also check this out, it's a potentially cleaner way to do this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33939206/2981429